# Measure light on surface

Tags: light, lighting

I'm pretty new with blender, I'm looking for a tool similar to this one for vray for 3ds max:

https://www.chaosgroup.com/blog/how-to-set-up-lighting-analysis-in-v-ray-next

I aim to make the lighting calculation (measure the average lux on the floor of a room)

Thanks

Comment: False colour has been in Blender since 2017.

Answer (score -2):

This is something quite similar:

[image]

Comment: No it isn't. It just looks similar. The colors are relative to the exposure settings, not to the light density on the surface. It is used for setting the exposure(or amount of light in the scene) since grey here should match middle grey so the purpose of it is completely different as well. This is a misleading answer.

Comment: You’ll have to explain how it is different to your idea of “light density on a surface”. Do you mean irradiance? Radiance before it hits a surface? What metric? The light direction is not there, but strictly speaking to the calculations, it would require explanation.